# Clicking on "notifications" consistently crashes the app

Tags: bug, android-app

When I click on "notifications" button on the top right the mobile app crashes every single time.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Google
- Device Model: Pixel 2

  - OS Version: 10 (5908170)

Comment: There's an app?! I honestly thought that was retired yonks ago.

Comment: It may be great to share the link to the app on Google Play so it's not mistaken for another. 

Comment: Development on the mobile apps has been abandoned some time ago, AFAIK. No fixes nor new features will be forthcoming I’m afraid.

Comment: @nyedidikeke https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin